# Exception message empty

Tags: c++, exception, stdstring

I have an exception class as follows:

```
class FileNotFoundException : public std::exception
{
public:
    FileNotFoundException(const char* message) : errorMessage(message){ }
    const char* what() const throw() override
    {
        return this->errorMessage;
    }
private:
    const char* errorMessage;
};
```

And I `throw` this exception like this:

```
std::string message = "Message";
throw ::FileNotFoundException(message.c_str());
```

But when I try to handle it using:

```
try
{
    // the code that throws 
}
catch(::FileNotFoundException& ex)
{
    std::string message = ex.what(); 
}
```

The `string` is empty.
If anyone can help, I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: Undefined behavior. When you `throw`, your `std::string message` goes out of scope, and is destroyed, and your `errorMessage` points to deallocated memory.

Comment: thank you, you are both correct. Stupid that I didnt think of anything this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just store a pointer to the message. Try either storing it in `std::string`, or, better, pass it to the parent constructor. Perhaps it's better to inherit from `std::runtime_error` in that case.

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class FileNotFoundException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
  FileNotFoundException(const char* message) : std::runtime_error(message)
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  try {
    throw ::FileNotFoundException("oops, something happened");
  }
  catch(const ::FileNotFoundException& ex) {
    std::cout << "Exception: '" << ex.what() << "'" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ g++ -W -Wall --std=gnu++11 a.cpp -oa
$ ./a
Exception: 'oops, something happened'
```

In short (and without details): The class `std::exception` doesn't have any constructors. It's just a parent class used by all other exceptions. On the other hand, `std::runtime_error` has a constructor that stores the message for you properly. A complete explanation can be found in [Difference: std::runtime_error vs std::exception()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569726/difference-stdruntime-error-vs-stdexception)

I think this approach is better than to define `what()` and using `std::string` to store the message yourself. That is, if you don't have special needs for the exception class.

You should also check out the [C++ exception hierarchy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. Also thanks for the example, I am going to accept this as the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Your example only fixes it because you pass a real constant string to the exception constructor, instead of having a seperate `std::string` variable on the stack whose pointer is passed. Passing that pointer to the parent constructor doesn't fix the behavior, the string will still not get copied.

Comment: @Matthias247 I don't know what the standard says about it, but GCC definitely copies the string (I've double checked). Worth looking into.

Comment: Seems true - I checked here now: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error
`std::runtime_error` seems to copy the constructor argument. Did not expect this.

Comment: It *may* be that most standard library authors just copy it anyway, because otherwise it would be very dangerous (you're jumping up the stack). So it could be a case where everyone does it, but it could also be the standard doesn't explicitly require it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
throw ::FileNotFoundException(message.c_str());
```

You are storing a pointer to memory owned by `message` in the exception. When `message` goes out of scope (which happens during the throw) the data will no longer be valid. Which means `this->errorMessage` returns some undefined memory. To fix it you can either pass some really constant string to your exception or you need the exception to own the string, e.g. by making `errorMessage` a `std::string`.